# iOS 14 Notification not show the image

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi I develop on iOS and follow through this instruction

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/rich-notifications/

and my "notification.apns" look like this

```
{
"Simulator Target Bundle": "com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"aps": {
    "category": "content_added_notification",
    "alert": {
        "title": "Photos",
        "body": "Antoine added something new - take a look"
    },
    "mutable-content": 1
},
"image_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Basketball_Ball_Icon.png" 
}
```

And notification show like this.

[image]

What wrong with it??

Comment: @matt Yes I did it. I created UNNotificationServiceExtension And add that 2 extension to that class. also code in NotificationService.

Answer (score 1):

Just reboot your device. It's another bug of new release I suppose

Comment: I tried but it won't help. it not go inside the notification service extension (it don't have [modified] as suffix)

Comment: Unblievable, but it works! I spend a day troubleshooting the problem.